# Endomorphism ring of a direct sum of tilting modules

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

I have found that a category of modules over a Lie algebra has an infinite number of (partial) tilting modules and that direct sum of these tilting modules is also an object in this category.

**What are the natural questions to ask about this category or objects afterwards?**

It seems to me that very often people study the endomorphism ring of this kind of direct sum and try to get properties and related equivalent categories (cf. works of Donkin, Soergel, Ringel about tilting modules). It is easy to hear the phrase *"one of the aims of tilting theory is to obtain new algebras from given algebras keeping (some of) the structure of their module categories",* but **what else to do?**

In our particular setting we don't expect our endomorphism ring to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: This isn't yet a real question.  What is a "tilting module" for "a Lie algebra" and what are your sources?   What field do you work over?   For semisimple Lie algebras over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0, some basic theory and references are given in Chapter 11 of my 2008 AMS book.   But the origins of the theory go back to representations of finite dimensional algebras and later to semisimple algebraic groups (especially in prime characteristic).   Typically each "block" involves only finitely many indecomposable tilting modules, with End algebras still under study.

Comment: @Jim Humphreys: My question was a little precipitated and I had to reconsider several different structures on my research level. So, I am sorry spending your time, I agree that it is not a real question in this way and I agree if it is closed!
